# Snippet translation not working in offcanvas

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've created a custom offcanvas (as a plugin) and I've extended `@Storefront/storefront/utilities/offcanvas.html.twig`. In the Twig file I placed among others a snippet like this `{{ 'enquiry.amount.subtitle'|trans|sw_sanitize }}`.

In the administration I filled in the translation for the snippet in EN, DE, ES and NL. But for some reason I'm always seeing the EN translation, no matter what language I've switched too.

I've used snippets before in my custom theme and then the translations are working just fine, but in the custom offcanvas it isn't working.

Any idea how this can happen?

**Edit**
When I dump `app.request.get('_locale')` in a page I'm getting `nl-NL`. But when I dump it in the offcanvas I'm getting `en-GB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce that on the current release `6.5.4.0`.

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/utilities/offcanvas.html.twig' %}

{% block utilities_offcanvas_meta %}
    {{ "foo.bar"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
{% endblock %}
```

With `foo.bar` having the value `foo` for locale `de-DE` and `bar` for `en-GB`, it did yield the expected result switching from the domain of one locale to the other.

Are you sure you're requesting the content of the offcanvas with the correct domain of the locale? Try and dump `{{ app.request.locale }}` somewhere in your template, to see the locale associated with the request.

For testing purposes you can also explicitly provide a locale for the translation. If your translations are set up correctly, this should definitively work.

```
{{ "foo.bar"|trans([], null, "en-GB") }}
{{ "foo.bar"|trans([], null, "de-DE") }}
```

Comment: {{ "enquiry.amount.subtitle"|trans([], null, "nl-NL") }} is outputting the right snippet, so what can cause the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're requesting the content of the offcanvas with the correct domain of the locale? I updated my answer with a way to check.

Comment: When I dump app.request.get('_locale') in a page I'm getting nl-NL. But when I dump it in the offcanvas I'm getting en-GB

Comment: The contents of the offcanvas are fetched using ajax. You must provide the url for the ajax request somewhere. The url you generate is for the domain associated with, what I presume is the default locale, `en-GB` despite whatever the current locale actually is. That's the problem.

Comment: `this.openOffCanvas('/enquiry/offcanvas', false, null, title);` where `'/enquiry/offcanvas` is the custom controller route. So I guess it has something to do with this part?

Comment: Yes. If your domain for the locale `nl` is `example.tld/nl` then you'd request `example.tld/enquiry/offcanvas` with this instead of `example.tld/nl/enquiry/offcanvas`. Use the twig function to generate the url instead `{{ path('frontend.my.route') }}`.  Where `frontend.my.route` would be the specific name given to the route in the annotation within your controller.

Comment: Thanks, I generated the URL from the path.